# If.....then statement not working properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, if-statement, streamreader

Good morning everyone.

I have this very weird problem.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
    Dim apantisi_pou_edwse As String
    Dim objreader As New StreamReader(TEST_NAME)
    Dim Answer1 As String = Split(objreader.ReadToEnd(), vbCrLf)(1) & vbCrLf

     If test1.RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
                apantisi_pou_edwse = test1.RadioButton1.Text.ToString()

            ElseIf test1.RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
                apantisi_pou_edwse = test1.RadioButton2.Text.ToString()
            End If
    If apantisi_pou_edwse = Answer1 Then
                RichTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
                RichTextBox1.Text = "Right answer!"
            ElseIf apantisi_pou_edwse <> Answer1 Then
                RichTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
                RichTextBox1.Text = "Sorry, wrong anwser"
            End If
```

So what that does is read a line from a text file and assign it to the string variable Answer1. 
It then takes the Text property of the appropriate radiobutton and assign it to the String variable apantisi_pou_edwse.
Last, it checks if apantisi_pou_edwse = Aswer1.
The problem is that even if the two are equal the if...then statement does not recognize them as such and move to the elseif section all times.
What am i missing? 
Thanks a lot

Edit

```
If String.Compare(apantisi_pou_edwse, Answer1) = 0 Then
            RichTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Green
            RichTextBox1.Text = "Συγχαρητήρια απάντησες σωστά"
        Else
            RichTextBox1.BackColor = Color.Red
            RichTextBox1.Text = "Λυπάμαι απάντησες λάθος"
        End If
```

I changed my if statement with the one above but it still does not work :(

Edit2
Thanks Mortalus and Enigmativity for their answers! They solved the problem

Comment: Probably that, for some reason, you've appended a `vbCrLf` on the end of the string you've read from the file, but the radio button texts don't contain that. Also, `Text` is a string already. Why call `ToString()` on it?

Comment: Also, `ElseIf apantisi_pou_edwse <> Answer1 Then` could just be `Else` - you've already established by the `If` that the two values do not match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line:

```
Dim Answer1 As String = Split(objreader.ReadToEnd(), vbCrLf)(1) & vbCrLf
```

to this:

```
Dim Answer1 As String = Split(objreader.ReadToEnd(), vbCrLf)(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a different method to compare strings at the following line:

```
If apantisi_pou_edwse = Answer1 Then
```

this line compares the references of the `apantisi_pou_edwse` with the `Answer1` variables

try using.

```
String.Compare(apantisi_pou_edwse, Answer1 )
```